# Difference between .next() and .children().eq(nextIndex)?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a child div and passing it to my function.
So far it works when I tried using and passing in `$parent.first(), $parent.next(), $parent.prev(), $parent.last()`.

But when I tried to pass in an index to get the div like `$parent.children().eq(someIndex)`. It doesn't recognise it. I tried console logging both and it does seem to have a slight difference, but I can't figure what the difference is and how I can solve it so I could pass in my divs without the restriction of only next and prev, etc?

This is what I get on console.log. Top is `.next()`, bottom is `.children().eq.(nextIndex)`.

```
[div.section, prevObject: n.fn.init[4], context: document]
[prevObject: n.fn.init[3], context: document]
```

What I have on the next buttons are

```
goTo( $sections.next() );
```

And the menu buttons are

```
$dotMenu.on( 'click', 'div', function( e ) {
    var thisIndex = $( this ).index();
    goTo( $sections.children().eq(thisIndex) );
});
```

Comment: You should share the relevant html and js.

Comment: What I have on the next buttons are
    goTo( $current.next() );

And the menu buttons are

    $dotMenu.on( 'click', 'div', function( e ) {
        var thisIndex = $( this ).index();
        goTo( $sections.children().eq(thisIndex) );
    });

Comment: you would need to go up 2 levels - `$parent.parent().children().eq(someIndex)` otherwise you are just getting siblings of the current level rather than siblings of the parent level - unless `$parent` is a collection, the you should just apply `.eq` directly to that `$parent.eq(someIndex)`

Comment: Ah... It is a one more level up issue. Thanks Pete!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for passing an index from any variable then i would suggest you to make use of `.find()`:

```
$parent.find('div').eq(someIndex)
```